# How to find number of queues bound to a particular exchange in rabbitmq?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am trying to implement the Publish/Subscribe model specified in the Rabbitmq Tutorials in java. The example provided there works fine. Now I want to modify it such a way that it restricts the number of clients accessing the Exchange.

When I looked into it I could find a command "rabbitmqctl list_bindings" to list the bounded queues, which is manual typing. Is there any way to do that programmatically?
or
Do we have any exchange function to return the number of queues bound to an exchange?

I could not find any,please help me, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [management UI](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) HTTP API, here you can find all the [API](https://raw.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_2/priv/www/api/index.html)

you can use the API `/api/exchanges/{vhost}/{exchange_name}/bindings/source`

for example:

```
http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/Topic_test/bindings/source
```

you will get a json as result, somethings like:

```
[

    {
        "source": "Topic_test",
        "vhost": "/",
        "destination": "test_0",
        "destination_type": "queue",
        "routing_key": "",
        "arguments": { },
        "properties_key": "~"
    },
    {
        "source": "Topic_test",
        "vhost": "/",
        "destination": "test_1",
        "destination_type": "queue",
        "routing_key": "",
        "arguments": { },
        "properties_key": "~"
    },
    {
        "source": "Topic_test",
        "vhost": "/",
        "destination": "test_2",
        "destination_type": "queue",
        "routing_key": "",
        "arguments": { },
        "properties_key": "~"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... It is still UI , what I am expecting is like, any way to retrieve the number of queue in the Java program itself. Like a method or some thing else programmatically.

Comment: Oh thanks Gabriele... I am new to this rabbitmq so I need some time to go through.. I'll get back to you once I work it out.

Comment: Agreed.  How can one get this programmatically from Java.

Comment: It is just an http call